# php dynamic function for list

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop, explode

I am trying to make dynamic function where user can create list without adding `<ul> <li>` tag.

here is my function

```
function the_main_nav($navlinks){
        echo '<nav>';
        echo '<ul>';

        $menuitem = $navlinks;
        $pieces = explode(",",$menuitem);

        $i=$navlinks;
        while($i==','){ 
            echo '<li>' . $pieces[$i] . '</li>';
            $i++;
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</nav>';      
    }
```

This is my template tag `the_main_nav('1,2,3,44 5');`

But its going into endless loop with error. I want auto generate `<li>` after each `','` commma. Also if possible I want anchor link within the list so it can be linked with the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `while` loop, use `foreach`:

```
foreach ( $pieces as $piece ) {
  echo '<li>' . $piece . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks just single line means lot... :) Can I add link for each li ?

Comment: Sure thing, you can put in `echo` everything what you need.

Comment: Yeh that I know now but I want each list li will have different url. How can i do that?

Comment: What url ? What pattern for them you would like to set ?

Comment: like with <li> I want to add <li><a href="..this is dynamic..or user input url...">

Answer (score 0):

Yep, using a foreach can be cool, but your error is in your logical view.
If I look at your algorithm I see :
Write some open tags
store my argument into a new variable called $menuitem
create an array from $menuitem each time you find a "," and store it in $pieces
store my argument into a new variable called $i
now while $i is equal to the char "," (which is allways false) write my subtags

after that write end tags.

You do not course your array. 
A foreach loop will do it. But to correct your code you must understand that $i must take as value the indexes of the array, so 0,1,2,3...